# Filter the dataframe according to a list of dates

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe for weather stations (short dataframe):

```
      import pandas as pd
      import numpy as np

      df_Station = pd.DataFrame({'Hemisphere': ['North', 'North', 'North', 'South'], 
                                 'Qtd_Instrumentation': [18, 5, 25, 10],
                                  'Year_Construction': [2015, 2008, 2016, 2020]})
```

I would like to generate a new dataframe. This would need to be filtered by the year the station was built. I tried to create a list containing the objective years and build the df_ as follows:

```
      list_years = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020] 
      df_Filter =  df_Station[df_Station['Year_Construction'] == list_years]
```

However, this code has the error: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

I would like the output (df_Filter) to be:

```
            print(df_Filter)

            Hemisphere  Qtd_Instrumentation Year_Construction
               North            18              2015
               North            25              2016
               South            10              2020
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for this type of filtering.

```py
df_Filter =  df_Station[df_Station['Year_Construction'].isin(list_years)]
```

Comment: I did not know this function. Worked perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

df_Station = pd.DataFrame({'Hemisphere': ['North', 'North', 'North', 'South'],
                           'Qtd_Instrumentation': [18, 5, 25, 10],
                           'Year_Construction': [2015, 2008, 2016, 2020]})

list_years = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
df_Filter = df_Station[df_Station['Year_Construction'].isin(list_years)]

print(df_Filter)
```

> Output

```
  Hemisphere  Qtd_Instrumentation  Year_Construction
0      North                   18               2015
2      North                   25               2016
3      South                   10               2020
```

Comment: There is a problem with your result. The year 2008 is not included in the list. Thanks.

Comment: Solved, printed different value earlier